# Selenium Python take elements from table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

how can I get the data inside the href attribute inside a table? With this HTML code.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="hospitals">
            <tbody><tr>
              <td>
              </td>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="/vehicles/1798010/patient/796603" class="btn btn-success">Trasporta paziente</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <a href="/vehicles/1798010/patient/548340" class="btn btn-success">Trasporta paziente</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="hidden-xs">
                    <span class="label label-warning">No</span>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="/vehicles/1798010/patient/516133" class="btn btn-success">Trasporta paziente</a>
              </td>
            </tr> 
      </tbody></table>
```

I would like them to return to me:/vehicles/1798010/patient/796603 , /vehicles/1798010/patient/548340 , /vehicles/1798010/patient/516133

Answer (score -1):

You can use `driver.execute_script` to select all the anchor elements in that table and get their href attributes.

```py
driver.get("some URL")
hrefs = driver.execute_script('return [...document.querySelectorAll("#hospitals a[href]")].map(x => x.getAttribute("href"))')
print(hrefs)
```